# Console QuickEdit in VS vs. executable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, console-application, executable, windows-console

A friend and I are making a console application in C++ and have run into some issues trying to disable QuickEdit mode. We're using the following code to do so:

```
DWORD prev_mode;
GetConsoleMode(hConsole, &prev_mode);
SetConsoleMode(hConsole, ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS | (prev_mode & ~ENABLE_QUICK_EDIT_MODE));
```

This works to disable QuickEdit mode when running in Visual Studio, however does not consistently work when directly running the executable outside of VS (and within the build directory).

Additionally, we have inconsistencies between what occurs while running the exact same code. For example:

- I am able to disable QuickEdit mode **both** while running in VS and by directly clicking the executable within the build directory, however as soon as I copy the executable to another directory, QuickEdit mode is no longer disabled.
- My friend is able to disable QuickEdit mode while running in VS, however **not** in the build directory.

What is happening that causes this? Would this be an issue with our code/understanding, or is this a known issue with QuickEdit?

Comment: Whether hInput HANDLE initialized with STD_INPUT_HANDLE?  `hConsole= GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);`

Comment: Yes, it's initialized beforehand.

Comment: I suggest you could use follow the following steps try to disable command window Quick Edit Mode once and for all:1) Close ALL console windows. 2) Right click on the top left of the console window and select Defaults. It must be Defaults and not Properties.3)Deselect Quick Edit in options. 4)Click OK and then close the console window. If the issue continue, it may a issue with QuickEdit, I suggest you could post the issue to the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) for better help.

Comment: That is a solution, however we intend to distribute the executable - so we'd rather do it programmatically, rather than require everyone do this fix.